# How to make use of keep-alive in ConnectionRequest in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I want to use the "Connection: keep-alive" method to improve the https performance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

However I can't find anything related to the reuse of connection in ConnectionRequest and NetworkManager.

Does codename one support this? If not, any alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We thought about adding an official implementation of this. An undocumented API is used by the open source pubnub support for Codename One.

However with later versions we added full TCP support and [websockets](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/invite-friends-websockets-windows-phone-more.html) which seem more appropriate for this type of use case.

Comment: Alright, thanks, though it will take me quite some time to move the current logics from ConnectionRequest to websockets....
So can we override the websockets, so that it supports self-signed SSL certificate now?

Comment: I don't think that's possible or even allowed by Apple with their latest restrictions.